# Adding a single projection to a criteria query

Tags: java, hibernate, object

I am new to hibernate and am struggling with adding a single projection to a criteria query. I am getting an error with the following code: "java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object, on line 29. I know it is something very simple, but I cant figure out what I am doing wrong here!

Code is as follows:

```
package com.simpleprogrammer;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Projection;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Projections;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(org.hibernate.Version.getVersionString());
    System.out.println("Creating session!");

    PopulateSampleData();
    Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", "Joe")).setProjection(Projections.property("id"));
    List<Object[]> results = criteria.list();

    for(Object[] result : results) {
        for (Object o : result)
            System.out.println("Name is " + o.toString());
    }
    session.close();
    HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().close();
}

private static void PopulateSampleData() {
    Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    User joe = CreateUser("Joe", 500, 50, "Good job", "You made it!");
    session.save(joe);

    User bob = CreateUser("Bob", 300, 20, "Taco time!");
    session.save(bob);

    User amy = CreateUser("Amy", 250, 200, "Yes!!!");
    session.save(amy);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}

private static User CreateUser(String name, int goal, int total, String... alerts) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setName(name);
    user.getProtienData().setGoal(goal);
    user.addHistory(new UserHistory(new Date(), "Set goal to " + goal));
    user.getProtienData().setTotal(total);
    user.addHistory(new UserHistory(new Date(), "Set total to " + total));
    for (String alert : alerts) {
        user.getGoalAlerts().add(new GoalAlert(alert));
    }
    return user;
}
}
```

Comment: can you point out where are you getting the error? Line 29 points to a closing brace: for(Object[] result : results) {
        for (Object o : result)
            System.out.println("Name is " + o.toString());
    }//Line 29

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `criteria.list()` is returning `List<Integer>` instead of `List<Object[]>` since a single column is fetched.
Try changing

```
List<Object[]> results = criteria.list();
```

to

```
List<Integer> results = criteria.list();
```

Comment: But the problem with that is that I cannot then loop through a set of Integer objects. If I change the for statement to be         for(Integer result : results) { it throws an error?

Comment: What's the exception you get?